# Wordmorphs IN SPACE!

Tags: knowledge, language, english, word-ladder

The year is 21XX. Space tourism is easy and affordable. You decide to spend your next vacation hopping from planet to planet, hanging out with aliens and so forth. To that end, you rent a WordMorphian spacecraft.

WordMorph is a propriety technology of Hasbro-Telsa that uses the power of words to take you anywhere in the galaxy, instantaneously. As an ordinary Earth citizen, you are only allowed to use WordMorph technology to visit planets within our solar system (other destinations are locked to prevent you from going anywhere else). These are the thirteen planets as officially recognized by the World Government:

```
Mercury
Venus
Earth
Mars
Jupiter
Saturn
Uranus
Neptune
Ceres
Pluto
Haumea
Makemake
Eris
```

---

To travel to a particular destination, you must perform a series of wordmorph operations to transform your current location word into the destination word.
The energy required to perform one wordmorph operation costs one hundred space dollars (S$100).

The WordMorph engine allows for four different types of wordmorph operations: letter addition, letter removal, letter replacement, and letter swap.

1. letter addition is adding any one letter into a word. Example: `Star -> Sitar`
2. letter removal is removing any one letter from a word. Example: `Star -> Tar`
3. letter replacement is replacing any one letter in a word with any other letter. Example: `Star -> Scar`
4. letter swap is swapping any one letter in a word with any other letter in that word. Example: `Star -> Tsar`

Every wordmorph word that is not a destination word must be an official Scrabble word. To be specific, it must be a valid entry in this online Scrabble dictionary tool: https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary

You can use words more than once, and visit a planet more than once.

---

Before you begin your journey, you should plan out a route (i.e. make a word list). You want to see as many planets as you can without getting lost on the wrong side of Saturn. In addition, you want to save as much space money as you can for partying with aliens.

**How many planets can you visit from Earth with a WordMorphian spacecraft, and what is a cost-effective way to visit all of them - the planets you *can* visit, which may be less than thirteen - in a round-trip?**

The person with the most cost-effective route will be marked as the answer.
I will share hints later on.

Please let me know if I should clarify something, and feel free to post a partial answer.

Good luck and safe travels!

Comment: Sorry but doesn't the question already imply that you can visit all of them? If there is an answer of the most cost effective way to visit all of them.

Comment: Also this puzzle seems like it is going to take a mammoth amount of work, don't you think it would be a better idea to scale down the number of planets to maybe 5 or 6.

Comment: And maybe have an order of planets.

Comment: Many planets look like they can't be morphed to/from a real word in one step, making them completely inaccessible.

Comment: "Them" refers to "The planets that you can visit". I didn't want to ask "How many planets can you visit... to visit all of the planets that you can visit...?". I'll update the question to be more precise if the language is unclear. The "mammoth amount of work" is a good criticism. Note, however, that this comment was written under the impression that one is expected to visit all thirteen. Still, if this is too much work, I'm hesitant to make it easier right away, as it's intended to be a challenge. I solved it, and I believe that others who are smarter than me can solve it as well.

Comment: It is just typing many random words into the search bar and hope to get lucky kind of a puzzle.

Comment: It is a challenge because it is tedious

Comment: A lot people could solve it if they hammered away at the search bars for days on end.

Comment: If this is not something you know how to solve easily, then that's okay. I have a lot of experience with word games, so for me it wasn't like that. I enjoy this stuff. Maybe someone like me will come along and enjoy it in the same way that I did. It could happen. So maybe my puzzle isn't that good, but comments like yours say much more about the type of person you are than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> Earth, eath, eat, meat mart, Mars, cars, cares Ceres, cares, cars, ears, eras, Eris, eras, ears, Mars, mans, manus, menus, Venus, menus, manus, mans, man, pan, pat, plat, plot, pluot, Pluto, pluot, plot, pot, port, pore, more, mere, merer, mercer, mercery, Mercury. 7 in total so far.